# Using Svcutil to create proxy class does not include XmlIgnore attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, svcutil.exe

Is there a way to have SvcUtil include the [XmlIgnore] attribute?

we need this attribute in our proxy classes (because we have Dictionaries that XmlSerialization does not like), but SvcUtil does not include these attributes in the generated proxies.

Comment: I don't get it. How are you using svcutil? If you've got dictionaries with [XmlIgnore] on them, then why would they ever appear in the WSDL?

Comment: We are actually using the proxy class generated to do XmlSerialization. XmlSerialization does not support Dictionaries, it throws an exception. SvcUtil does not look at XmlIgnore when generating the proxy. You'd think that XmlSerialization and SvcUtil/WSDL would behave the same but they are slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find an automatic way to do this. We just have had to put the tags on manually after creating the proxy.